# Form input not cleared after ajax submission

Tags: ajax, drupal-8

I have a form with one field and a submit button with ajax submission option like following -

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $id = 0)
{       
    $form['fieldset']['message'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#default_value' => "",
        '#required' => true,
        '#attributes' => array(
            'placeholder' => t('write here'),
        ),
    );

    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Send'),
        '#attributes' => array(
            'class' => array(
            ),
        ),
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => [$this, 'Ajaxsubmit'],
            'event' => 'click']
    );
    return $form;
}
```

The ajax function is following -

```
public function Ajaxsubmit(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
        $db_values = [
            "message" => $form_state->getValue("message"),
            "date_create" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        ];
        $save = DbStorage::Insert($db_values);
        //$('#mychat_form input').val("");
        //$form_state->setValue('content', NULL);

        $response = new AjaxResponse();

        if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors() || !$save) {
               $response->addCommand(new AlertCommand('something wrong!'));
        } else {

        $message = DbStorage::Get(["id" => $save]);
        $send_id = $message->send_id;
        $build = [
                '#theme' => "chat_view",
                '#message' => $message,
                '#sender' => $send_id,
                '#current_user' => true
            ];
        $ans_text = render($build);
        $response->addCommand(new AppendCommand('#mychat', $ans_text));
        }
        return $response;

    }
```

Here form data submission is working fine. But input data is not cleared after submission. I tried to clear it from my javascript using -

```
$('#my_form input').val("");
```

But the problem is my javascript file is called every 3 seconds and the form input is also cleared in every 3 seconds. this is problematic for users. Is there any other way to clear the form input after the ajax submission ? Can i do anything inside Ajaxsubmit function ?

Comment: Have you tried the DataCommand() `$response->addCommand(new DataCommand('#my_form input', 'value',''));`

Comment: you mean, in the form, instead of $response->addCommand(new AppendCommand('#mychat', $ans_text)); i should use $response->addCommand(new DataCommand('#mychat', $ans_text)); ?

Comment: Add Both `$response->addCommand(new DataCommand('#mychat', $ans_text));` is for updating the `#mychat`. The other one for replacing `$('#my_form input').val("");` from JS.

Comment: my JS is run every 3 seconds. is it a good idea to clear the input form from JS ?

Comment: what about scrolling ? i need to keep the scroll bar at the bottom unless the the scrollbar is dragged. here why $("#mychat").blur(function() not working ?

Comment: i used both like             $response->addCommand(new DataCommand('#my_form input', 'value', ''));
            $response->addCommand(new AppendCommand('#my_chat', $ans_text)); but it is not clearing the form

Comment: Did you add `
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\DataCommand;` at the top.

Comment: yes i added use Drupal\Core\Ajax\DataCommand;` at the top. but it is not clearing the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [InvokeCommand](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Ajax%21InvokeCommand.php/class/InvokeCommand/8.5.x) for doing it.

For e.g: to clear an input value `$('#my_form input').val("");` in ajax response

```
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AppendCommand;
:

$form['fieldset']['message'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => "",
  '#required' => true,
  '#attributes' => array(
    'placeholder' => t('write here'),
    'class' => ['custom-class'],
  ),
);
```

In Ajax function

```
:
$build = [
  '#theme' => "chat_view",
  '#message' => $message,
  '#sender' => $send_id,
  '#current_user' => true
];
$response->addCommand(new AppendCommand('#mychat', $build));
$response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('.custom-class', 'val', ['']));
```

Comment: it clears the form first time, but from the second time, when i enter new message, the submit button does not work and form input is not cleared

Comment: anyway, should i use $('#my_form input').val(""); in my javascript file too ?

Comment: my form definition is  $form['fieldset']['message'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#default_value' => "",
        '#required' => true,
        '#attributes' => array(
            'placeholder' => t('write here'),
        ),
    ); how to add custom class here ?

Comment: many thanks. do i also need to add $('#my_form input').val(""); in my JS ?

Comment: it worked ! but sometimes it is showing a message twice in chatbox

Comment: No need to add it in JS. May be you are clicking the button twice.